# I can't setup jQuery on vscode

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-code

I am new to Stackoverflow, this is my very first question ever, I'm not sure how it all works yet, and I hope I will be able to explain my problem correctly. I was trying to use jQuery in vscode, so I installed Node.js, and then followed [this tutorial on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GjqogBulgtE); I typed `npm install tsd -g`, then `npm install typings --global`, and finally `typings install dt~jquery --global` in my terminal, as the guy in the tutorial said, and eventually the folder: "typings" appeared into project folder.
[image: This is the picture of the folder that appeared].

After that, the guy copied the content of the last file, called "index.d.ts", which in my case contained `/// <reference path="globals/jquery/index.d.ts" />`, into the "plugins.js" file, stored in the JS folder. As you can see, I do not have that folder and that file. What do I have to do? Have I committed a mistake in creating the whole project, or do I have to create a JS folder from scratch? And if so how? I know very little about vscode and jQuery, typescript... I hope someone can help, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to explain on file structure similar to yours

[image: structure]

With the last command we generated `typings` folder. Inside `typings/globals/jquery/index.d.ts` you can see Typescript declarations that will be used for suggestions in VS Code:

[image]

Now we need to modify our `index.js` to use these typings. With arrows I am showing how import works. We add reference path for `typings/index.d.ts`. `typings/index.d.ts` just reexports typings from `globals/jquery/index.d.ts` (see `/// <reference path="globals/jquery/index.d.ts" />` inside it).

[image]
[image]

After making this kind of chaining, we can type in our js file and have automatic suggestions

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. That solved my problem; I didn't know it was that easy to fix, so sorry if I wasted your time... :)